# Crop video in random positions

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I want to crop my video in a random position..Usually we use code : Crop=a:b:x:y
I see an example of being able to complete random positions
"drawtext=fontfile=font.ttf:fontsize=80:fontcolor=yellow@0.5:text='studentname': 
x=if(eq(mod(t,30),0),rand(0,(W-tw)),x): 
y=if(eq(mod(t,30),0),rand(0,(H-th)),y)" 
but it applies to text and watermark.
how can i apply crop to video. Not to mention the use of the sins function camera effect. because I already have it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `random` function to randomize the x and y values.

`crop=W:H:x=random(0)*(iw-ow):y=random(0)*(ih-oh)`

random will return a value between 0 and 1.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. I wonder if I want every 10 seconds I want it to change the crop position. What more do I have to do?